# It's the first time he has driven or been driving a car

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I had always known that we generally use the present perfect simple for things that we do **for the first time**. Here is a classic example from the English Grammar in Use self-study book by Cambridge University Press:

> We say: lt's the (first) time something **has happened**. For example:
>
> > Don is having a driving lesson. It's his first one.
> >     It's the first time he **has driven** a car.

But now I found the following in a supplementary exercises book:

> Tick (✓) the sentence which means the same as the first sentence.
>
> > This is the first time I'**ve been skiing**.
> >
> > - I'**ve been skiing** once before.
> > - I **haven't been skiing** for a long time.
> > - I'**ve never been skiing** before. **✓**

This suggests that we **can** use the present perfect continuous in some cases for things that we do for the first time but it seems like both of the examples are about an ongoing activity which makes both of them look very similar even though tenses used are different.

When do we prefer the present perfect **continuous** to present perfect **simple** and vice versa for things that we do for the first time?

Comment: That's also a present perfect, with *been* being the past participle. You could replace *been* with *gone* there.

Comment: The skiing example is quite involved. We say for the present: to go skiing: I'm going skiing today. The  simple past then is: went skiing or past continuous forms are: have been skiing and have been going skiing. For the activity. But: He's skiing well today, isn't he? That is just the verb to ski, and not the verb to go skiing.

Comment: @Lambie What's your point?

Comment: I got it. Here "have been skiing" is not the past perfect continuous of "ski", but rather the past perfect simple of "go skiing". Thank you! Should one of you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Lambie By the way, would it sound natural to say "It's the first time I've skied"?

Comment: The best way would be; **This** is the first time I've skied. or: **This** is the first time I've been skiing. Thanks for working that out for me! You did indeed get it. I kept writing it out and getting confused. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common collocations are: **to go skiing**, **to go swimming**, etc. Thus, we say:

- I **go** swimming twice a week.
- We **went** skiing yesterday.
- They've **gone** skiing, but they should be back soon.
- I've **been** skiing three times this year.
- This is the first time I've **been** skiing.

In the last two examples **been** was used as the past participle of **go**. We use it to mean that somebody has gone somewhere and come back.

Here, therefore, **have been skiing** is not the present perfect continuous form of **ski**, but rather the present perfect simple of **go skiing**.

Special credits go to [@Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/33113/lambie) and [@userr2684291](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3395/userr2684291) for leading me in the right direction (see comments below the main post).

Comment: Compare to the sentence, "This is the first time I've been wrong," which has exactly the same structure as your example, without the confusion of an **-ing** word.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Yeah, but in order to identify the structure (i.e. the present perfect simple) I have to understand where -ing word comes from. Here I failed to do so.